# Taskbar icon doesn't show up on window based console window

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, auto-py-to-exe

Hi everyone I am an amateur programmer creating GUI's. I use auto-py-to-exe when I choose my console window as "Window Based(hide the console)" before creating my .exe file the icon doesn't show up on taskbar, it shows the default picture of itself. But when I choose "Console Based" there is no problem with that. Is there a way of dealing with this. Besides in both ways after creating .exe my icon doesn't show up on left top and when I alt+tab it shows the default icon again.

I also add .png's into labels, when I run it as .py on Visual Studio Code it shows the pictures that I've added but when I create .exe it doesn't show them aswell.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8L2L.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFnKh.png)

(The .ico and .png's are in the same file with my .py file)

I tried each and every combination on auto-py-to-exe but couldn't find a solution also copied the code written in there and added some different codes I found online but non of them has worked.

I have checked the solution advices on other topics but they didn't work.

Comment: Are you also setting the [`windowIcon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#windowIcon-prop) for the application (and the window)?

Comment: Yes I already did that but it doesn't work
                                        
`self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('logo.png'))`

Comment: That line just assumes that a `logo.png` file exists in the program execution context, which may not be the case for a pyinstaller bundle. Did you include that icon in the package? And what's its path, relative to the working dir of the file that calls that function?

Comment: Yes you can see it on the 2nd ss i've uploaded on "Additional Files" section

Comment: Have you actually checked that that file is available in the program context and is a valid image file? `QFile.exists('logo.png')` and `not QIcon('logo.png').isNull()`? If you have other images in your script, do they work as expected? Otherwise, it could be a plugin problem (image loading uses specific platform libraries that exist outside of the base Qt modules), and you have to ensure that you include all related plugins to the bundle too. Can you list the contents of all files included in your bundle?

Comment: When I run mycode on VS Code it shows the pictures and all that. But as I convert it to an .exe file it doesn't. I seriously didn't understand why this occurs.

Comment: please answer all questions asked above. Just put some appropriate debug prints, and run the binary in a command prompt to see their output.